# How to compare multiple values more efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x

Some simple code that compares prices from multiple stores, but I'm wondering what would happen if 10+ prices needed to be compared and the result to be *only* the most expensive/cheapest out of the 10+...

Is there an easier way to compare them without writing excess lines of code for efficiency? Maybe if statements?

```
walmart = input("Enter walmart price: ")
dollarstore = input("Enter Dollar store price: ")
amazon = input("Enter Amazons price: ")

exstore4 = input("Enter Example Store 4 price: ")
exstore5 = input("Enter Example Store 5 price: ")

if walmart <= dollarstore and dollarstore <= amazon:
    print("Walmart has the cheapest price.")
elif dollarstore <= amazon and amazon <= walmart:
    print("Dollar Store has the cheapest price.")
elif amazon <= walmart and walmart <= dollarstore:
     print("Amazon has the cheapest price.")
elif amazon <= dollarstore and dollarstore <= walmart:
     print("Amazon has the cheapest price.")
elif walmart == amazon and amazon == dollarstore:
    print("All stores have the same price.")
else:
    print("Something isnt right...")
```

Comment: maybe not as for better code but `walmart <= dollarstore and dollarstore <= amazon` could be written as `walmart <= dollarstore <= amazon`

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in an array with `name`, then sort them and get their names

```py
walmart = input("Enter walmart price: ")
dollarstore = input("Enter Dollar store price: ")
amazon = input("Enter Amazons price: ")

exstore4 = input("Enter Example Store 4 price: ")
exstore5 = input("Enter Example Store 5 price: ")

values = [
    {"name": 'Wallmart', "value": walmart},
    {"name": 'Dollar store', "value": dollarstore},
    {"name": 'Amazons', "value": amazon},
    {"name": 'Example Store 4', "value": exstore4},
    {"name": 'Example Store 5', "value": exstore5},
]

values.sort(key=lambda a: a["value"])

# get only 1 store:
print(values[0]["name"] + ' has the cheapest price.')

# or find all cheapest store:
# Find last same price index
i=1
while i<len(values) and values[i]['value'] == values[0]['value']: i+=1

if i==len(values): print('All stores have the same price.')
elif i==1: print(values[0]["name"] + ' has the cheapest price.')
else: print(' and '.join([value["name"] for value in values[0:i]]) + ' have the cheapest price.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
walmart = input("Enter walmart price: ")
dollarstore = input("Enter Dollar store price: ")
amazon = input("Enter Amazons price: ")

exstore4 = input("Enter Example Store 4 price: ")
exstore5 = input("Enter Example Store 5 price: ")
i = (walmart, dollarstore, amazon, exstore4, exstore5)
cheapest = min(i)
print(cheapest)
if cheapest == walmart:
    print("Walmart has the cheapest price of", cheapest)
elif cheapest == dollarstore:
    print("Dollar Store has the cheapest price of", cheapest)
elif cheapest == amazon:
     print("Amazon has the cheapest price of", cheapest)
elif walmart == amazon and amazon == dollarstore:
    print("All stores have the same price.")
else:
    print("Something isnt right...")
```

Comment: It's a pleasure..... Have a nice day.